# C# compiler type inference with dynamic function parameters

Tags: c#, var, type-inference

When I call a function and replace one of the parameters with dynamic, the compiler inferres the function result to be dynamic. I don't understand why this happens.

Example: the inferred type for a is dynamic, so this code compiles, but of course fails at runtime with RuntimeBinderException:

```
dynamic b = "";
var a = MethodWithoutOverloads("", b);
a.DoesNotExist();
```

...

```
public string MethodWithoutOverloads(string a, string b) { ... }
```

Somebody knows why the type inferred is not the return type of the function?

EDIT: edited to make clear this happens with methods without overloads

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right in the sense that the compiler *could* reason out that all `String.Format` overloads return a `string` and therefore infer that `a` must be a string no matter what `b` really is.

The truth is that the compiler does not do that. It solves the general case, which is good, and because overloads with different return types are valid in C#, it simply assigns the return type as dynamic and lets the runtime figure it out.

Answering your specific question,

```
public string MethodWithoutOverloads(string a, string b) { ... }
dynamic a = "";
var result = MethodWithoutOverloads(a, a); // result is dynamic.
```

Lets imagine the compiler decides that `result` is `string` and you publish to the wild west your library. Then, later on, you decide to add an overload with the following signature:

```
public int MethodWithoutOverloads(int a, int b) { ... }
```

Now, what should the type of `result` be? And, what happens to existing code that relied on `result` being strongly typed to `string`?

```
string result = MethodWithoutOverloads(someDynamicVariable, someOtherDynamicVariable);
```

The semantics change completely; before a consumer had a safe strongly typed variable, now he suddenly has a potentially unsafe implicit cast that can blow up in runtime.

Answer (score 3):

Because the compiler doesn't know *which* method is going to be invoked at run time.

For example, you may have the two methods:

```
int MyMethod(int a)
{
    return 5;
}

double MyMethod(string a)
{
    return 6.0;
}
```

And you write the following code:

```
dynamic myThing = 5;
var myResult = MyMethod(myThing);
```

Considering we've explicitly said `myThing` is *dynamic*, and this its type is to be determined at runtime, we have no idea which method will be invoked (if any). Thus, we don't know the return type, either.

Comment: This happens when I have one method, i.e. when there's no ambiguity. String.Format is not a good example, but type inference also fails when I call my own method when there's no ambiguity.

Comment: @Lev That's correct. *Technically* the compiler may be able to figure it out with no ambiguity, but I would suppose that would require a lot more work for seemingly not much gain. Whenever `dynamic` is part of an expression, the result will also by `dynamic`. If you're sure you know the type, simply be explicit with the variable type rather than using `var`

Comment: Ok so basically it's a case of "we didn't implement type inference for this case"...

Comment: @Lev If the compiler did what you say, what happens if later on someboday adds an overload that returns something else? You'd suddenly break existing code, seems like a fragile path to go down.